# Excel 2010/2013 intermittently pauses when saving workbooks via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've had an intermittent problem for the last couple years and it's finally gotten to the point where I really need to try tracking down a solution.

I'm running a VBA script that takes various csv files that are spit out over the course of the day and chops them up for use in various other processes.

Every 20 minutes it opens a workbook with a 'Workbook_Open' block that does the work. When it finishes the job it closes the Excel application. It does this all day, every day.

MOST of the time this goes off without a hitch. OCCASIONALLY, it will hang up as it's trying to save a workbook.  What I see when I catch it is the "Save as" box with the file path/name and the cancel button.  It just waits there until someone clicks "Cancel" or the system fails from trying to open Excel too many times.

If I catch it and click the button then it will proceed on as if nothing abnormal had happened.  Otherwise it just waits there for the user to click the button, as if it were any other msgbox/inputbox.

The weird thing is that the file is saved regardless of whether or not I click "Cancel" or kill the application or whatever.  There doesn't seem to be any pattern to when it happens.

I've tried searching for similar issues but all my searches inevitably come up with results relating to system/application crashes. This isn't that.  Excel will continue as normal, even to the point of continuing to save files in the way it SHOULD behave, if I click cancel.

Help?

Comment: Does any part of the code actually do a `.Save` or `.SaveAs`? When you catch the open SaveAs dialog, can you break & enter debug to see what line is causing this?

Comment: What error handling is there to catch the intermittent problem?

Comment: It's an automated process.  Any error handling is set up to send me an email with whatever error code has been encountered then to quit the application.    When this happens no error is generated. At least no email is sent.  As far as breaking, it just stops the code completely.  If there are routines I could add to try and catch it, I'd be happy to start there.

Comment: To more directly answer the 'is there a `.Save` or `.SaveAs`, yes.  There are both. I can't swear which it's hanging at.  The process starts with the .csv, then saves it as an .xlsx, does some trimming and calculating, then saves it as a different name to reflect the processed version vs. the raw form.

Comment: I was able to catch it today.  It won't actually break when pressing Ctrl-C.  I just have the window:  **Saving**  _Saving as: 'filepath and name.xlsx'_  When I click cancel it goes on as if no error has occurred.  At this point I'm not convinced it's an error at all.  At least not in the normal sense.  Has anyone experienced something like this where a lag or temporary connection failure with a network drive might cause similar symptoms?  My next step is to start trying to save to a local drive and see if the problem persists.

Comment: OK, final (I hope) follow up.  I re-coded the routine to save everything locally to the hard drive then moved the files to the network via the `.FileSystemObject` method and, I'm GUESSING, since there's no msgbox to pop up and hang on it's worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding calls to DoEvents before and after the .SAVEAS or .SAVE calls.  It's just two days, but this seems to have taken a process that I run daily multiple times a day (that creates multiple workbooks to a shared drive and never got through a day without this bug happening) to being a perfectly hands off process.